# C FILE pointer, why not just use the FILE type directly?

Tags: c, file, pointers

I know that in C we have to declare a pointer to the FILE type. Why can't we directly just use the FILE type instead of having to use a pointer to the FILE?

```
FILE *file;
FILE file; // Why can't we use this instead?
```

Answer (score 5):

A `FILE` is a *resource*. A given file only exists once and cannot move around. This makes a `FILE` unsuitable for C's value semantics. Whenever you have a resource, you refer to the resource by passing around a pointer to the resource, which is what the C API is doing.

(Moreover, the definition of `FILE` is private to the implementation and not part of the standard, which is an essential piece of freedom that you want implementers to have.)

Comment: As a note, C11 (n1570) 7.21.1 p2 requires `FILE` to be a (complete) “object type”, so `FILE file;` is valid, but as far as I can see, utterly useless (the only thing one can do with it portably is to zero it, I think).

Answer (score 2):

C originally didn't have the ability to pass structures by value, this was added in ANSI C89.

`FILE` wouldn't have worked in K&R C. Since `FILE *` works just fine, there was no need or benefit to redesign the functions to work with `FILE` instead of `FILE *` when ANSI C was being drafted.

As Kerrek SB points out, another benefit of `FILE *` is that `FILE` could be a typedef'd struct tag and this leaves the implementation free to implement it in whichever way is best, without breaking any working programs.